# IOS RxSwift crashing on device when installed manually via submodule

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a very old IOS project with mix Objc and Swift. We would like to use RxSwift for the next big feature coming soon. We tried installing rxSwift via Cocoapods but when I put in the "#use_framesworks" line in the pods file, the entire project goes crazy. Something about dynamic vs static frameworks.

So we decided to add RxSwift manually. Add git submodule, drag the project file and link binary with libraries in the build phases.

I can actually import RxSwift and RxCocoa and even write the code and it works on simulator.

However the moment I run the app on a device, it crashes at the very first sight of any Rx related code. In my case would be the declaration of DisposeBag(). I have no idea what to do. I hope someone could shed some light. Please find some screen shots below. There is nothing in the Xcode Logs as well. Just (lldb)

[image: Link Binary with libraries]

[image]

Comment: it will occur in many scenario, plz add your console report, does not related to RXSwift

Comment: @Anbu.karthik The console just prints (lldb)

Comment: are you created the any duplicate name or any other missed outlet connections, etc.. plz check once

Comment: @Anbu.karthik Everything works in simulator

Comment: simulator does not throw the error , enable the zombies and check once where will . the exception occurs

Answer (score 0):

In build phases, under Link binaries that you showed in the screenshot, look for "Copy files". Try adding it there, it solved the same problem for me with another framework (which I also manually added instead of through the podfile).

[image]